# Can partial_sort's middle iterator equal the end iterator?

Tags: c++, sorting, undefined-behavior

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partial_sort/, the `middle` argument is a:

> Random-access iterator pointing to the element within the range
> `[first,last)` that is used as the upper boundary of the elements that
> are fully sorted.

Specifically, `middle` isn't allowed to be equal to `last`. However, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort seems to have entirely different documentation and doesn't mention any range restrictions (but obviously `middle` shouldn't be outside `[first, last]`).

Is behavior defined when `middle == last`?

Comment: The lesson here is that one of those sites tends to be more reliable than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description of `std::partial_sort`  in the standard (N4659, 28.7.1.3/2) reads

> 2. *Effects:* Places the first `middle - first` sorted elements from the range `[first, last)` into the range `[first, middle)`. The rest of the elements in the range `[middle, last)` are placed in an unspecified order.

I see nothing here that would prohibit `middle` from equaling `last`.

Answer (score 3):

> Can partial_sort's middle iterator equal the end iterator?

Yes, it can. In that case the effect is same as using `std::sort`.

The standard specifies the preconditions like this:

> Preconditions: [first, middle) and [middle, last) are valid ranges.